# What does the << mean?

Tags: c#

Thanks for taking a look at this question.

I saw the following piece of code inside a traditional for block, but was not sure what its significance was inside its context.

`index <<= 1;`

For further context, here is the full block of code.

```
ulong index = 1;
int distance = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
{
    if ((hash1 & index) != (hash2 & index))
    {
        distance++;
    }

    index <<= 1;
}
```

Is it simply making sure that index is still 1 and if it isn't, return it's value to 1?

Secondly, what is this called so I can read up on it some more.

Finally, Thank you for your time and consideration for this matter.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/a1sway8w.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understand the shift operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460562/understand-the-shift-operator)

Comment: Thanks guys, I appreciate it.

Even the smug replies as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code in question is spinning through a pair of 64-bit hashes (probably as `ulong`s, like the `index`), and checking how many **bits** differ between them.  I'm going to use 4-bit values for example purposes, but the principle is the same.

---

```
 if ((hash1 & index) != (hash2 & index))
```

The `&` operator is doing a bitwise-AND operation.  When the hash is ANDed with the index value, you get either 0 or the index value back, depending on whether *that specific bit* was 0 or 1.  (`1010 & 0010 == 0010` and `1010 & 0100 == 0000`).
If both ANDs produce a 0, or both produce the index value, then the two bits of the hash match.  Otherwise, they don't, and we `distance++;` to indicate that they are off by one more bit than we knew of before.

```
index <<= 1;
```

This line merely bumps the index digit to the next bit.  It does this by taking the old index (which starts as `1`, equal to `0001`), and [left shifting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/a1sway8w.aspx) by one place (`<< 1`), then setting that back into the `index` variable (`<<=` instead of `<<`).  So after the first loop, `index` will be `0010`, then `0100`, and so on.

This has the effect of multiplying by 2, but that's not its intended use here.

---

So overall, you'd get a `distance` of 2 by running `0011` and `1111` through this algorithm, because two bits are different.

Comment: Thank you very much Bobson! I appreciate the in-depth answer!

It's been many moons since I have last done any bit shifting. In fact, I've only ever done bit shifting in college classrooms, and not in the actual real world.

Comment: @MrB - I can't recall a time that I've actually used it in the real world either, except when implementing someone else's algorithm which included it (like this hash-distance checker).  Glad it helped.

Comment: Interesting to note that you can do the same thing with `result = index ^ hash;`, and then counting the set bits using one of the methods described on the [bithacks page](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetParallel).

Comment: @JimMischel - I'd had the thought of using the XOR of the hashes, which is much simpler than iterating over each bit, but then I realized you still needed to do the bit counting on the result.  It becomes a speed/complexity tradeoff.

Comment: Yes, the bithacks counting methods are somewhat more complex. Only necessary if speed is a primary consideration.

Answer (score 4):

The code

```
index <<= 1;
```

Is a left shift by one bit. It has the same effect in this case as multiplying by two. But see comments for cautions.

Comment: just for clarity, when written in long hand is index = index << 1;

Comment: It is **not** the same thing as multiplying by two. That's a dangerous simplification. It's similar, and it can be used interchangeably, but only if you can guarantee that `index` is *always* less than (2^63). If it's 2^63 or greater (2^31 for `unit`), a real `*2` operation will throw an exception  (assuming you don't use `unchecked`), while the `<<= 1` will silently return the wrong number.