# What X >>= N does?

Tags: c#, bitwise-operators

I have this code:

```
tmp = (uint)len;
writer.CurPosition = value + 1;
do
{
    value++;
    writer.dest.WriteByte((byte)((tmp & 0x7F) | 0x80));
} while ((tmp >>= 7) != 0);
```

But I don't understand how `tmp >>= 7` works?

Comment: Looks like a bit shift operator to me. The tmp gets reassigned to the result of  bit shift operation. See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460562/understand-the-shift-operator

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25495042/what-is-the-operator-in-c/25495211#25495211

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`>>` is called **right bitwise-shift** operator. And since there is and additional `=` after `>>` (forming a **compound assignment** operator `>>=`), thus the *assigned* and the *assigner* variable (`tmp`) will be *shared*.

Or in other words, using the given example,

```
tmp >>= 7; //actually you use tmp both to assign and to be assigned
```

is equivalent to

```
tmp = tmp >> 7; //actually you use tmp both to assign and to be assigned
```

Now about the **bitwise-shift** operation, I think it is best to illustrate it by using an example.

Suppose the value of `tmp` is `0xFF00` (`1111 1111 0000 0000` in binary representation), then if we see in the bitwise level, the operation of `>>=` would look like this

```
1111 1111 0000 0000 //old tmp
------------------- >> 7
0000 0001 1111 1110 //Shifted by 7 -> this is going to be the new value for tmp
```

Thus, the new value for `tmp` would be `0x01FE` (that is `0000 0001 1111 1110`)

Answer (score 2):

`>>` is a bit shift operator

`tmp >>= 7` is shifting `tmp` 7 bits to the right and setting it to that value.

The loop will continue until `tmp` is *zero*

Comment: Yes, I know what is bit shift but it's the first time I see it's reassigned. Thank you!

Comment: @Vlad think of it as a `+=` only instead of with addition, it's with bit shifting

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a part of C and C++, called a [Compound assignment operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Compound_assignment_operators).

```
tmp >>= 7
```

is equivalent to

```
tmp = tmp >> 7
```

with `>>` as the **bitwise right shift**.