# How to bit-shift a register to zero?

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

When you left-shift (<<) or right-shift (>>) an integer register, you pull in zeros from the opposite side. It stands to reason that if you shift by more than the width of a register (e.g. shift a uint by 32 or more bits), it should become all zeros. In C#, this is not what happens. Instead, the shift count is effectively interpreted mod the register width, so it is impossible to definitively make the register zero using shifts. This is a pain.

I got hit by this because I am representing an extra-large integer via a unit[]. When you perform bit shifts on the extra-large register, in general bits from different uint instances in the array must "mix", so the code does stuff like:

```
  s[i] = (s[i+k] << n) | (s[i+k+1] >> (32 - n))
```

but this code fails when n = 0 or 32, i.e. when the shift corresponds to a pure shift among uint values with no mixing. (It's easy to write the code so that n = 32 never appears, but then the shift by (32 - n) still fails when n = 0.) For now, I have got around this problem by special-casing n = 0, but this is extra code (ugly) and an extra test-and-branch in a performance-critical spot (bad).

Can anyone suggest a modification (maybe using masking instead of or in addition to bit shifting?) to get around this difficulty? Can anyone explain why C# made the choice to make shift counts not behave according to naive expectations?

Comment: [Cast to `ulong`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/460568/11683) before shifting?

Comment: @GSerg Doh! That is the obviously correct way to handle my specific uint scenario, and I suspect on 64-bit hardware (which uses 64-bit registers even for 32-bit numbers) it is a zero-cost fix. But of course the same problem arises for someone using ulongs, and unfortunately for them there is no bigger language-native register for them to live within.