Is logical shift left by word size undefined behavior in C#?
I'm writing .NET 8 code to generate bit masks of various sizes. These masks are generated on the "hot path" in my code, so performance is important. I have the following method:
public static ulong Mask(int bitsize)
{
    return (1ul << bitsize) - 1ul;
}

used in the following way:
using System;

var r = new ulong[3];
test(r);

foreach (var u in r)
{
    Console.WriteLine(u);
}

void test(ulong [] result) {
    result[0] = mask(32);
    result[1] = mask(63); 
    result[2] = mask(64);
}
  
static ulong mask(int bitsize)
{
    return (1ul << bitsize) - 1u;
}

My expectation was that I should be able to create a mask of "all ones" by calling mask(64). This would shift in 64 zero bits, from which 1 is subtracted. Instead, I'm seeing the JITter generate "all zeros". Wrapping the returned value in unchecked makes no difference.
This reminds me of undefined behavior in C++: if you do <forbidden-thing>, anything can happen in the program. The subtraction after the shift seems to have been completely lost.
Naturally, I can pre-calculate the mask values for bitsize ranging from 0 to 64, and do a table lookup, but a table lookup is going to be bigger/slower than simply:
mov eax, 1
shlx rax, rax, rcx
dec rax
ret

which the JITter can aggressively inline for great success.
So, is 1ul << 64 undefined behavior in C#? Is there another way to generate bitmasks dynamically without introducing branches in the code?

Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460562/understand-the-shift-operator, but I’m not sure which question is better written.

1ul << 64 results in overflow. It tries to move the first bit 64 places to the left, ie the 65th bit

@PanagiotisKanavos "1ul << 64 results in overflow". no, it doesn't and no, it doesn't; for the first "no, it doesn't": the answers already discuss the low bit mask; for the second "no, it doesn't", see https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators - "Bitwise and shift operations never cause overflow" (emphasis mine) - sure, some bits might be discarded, but that's not the same thing

@MarcGravell I was talking about bits in general, not how C# treats this. 1ul << 64 would produce something that can't be represented in 64-bits.

Something from my college days whispers that if 2's complement was used the final result would be valid, but by now I have to look up what 2's complement means.

Huh, unchecked{ Console.WriteLine("{0:b}",(1L<<63 )-1); } works. Wikipedia says 2's complement is the common way to represent signed numbers. I remember that 2's complement operations result in valid results even if intermediate results overflow, assuming the final result is in range. I still have to read the entire article to remember how they work though

If I were you I'd probably just make an enum with 64 values. You can generate the code for that using Enumerable.Range(0, 63).Select(i => $"x{i} = {Mask(i)},")


So, is 1ul << 64 undefined behavior in C#?

Nope. From section 12.11 of the draft C# 8 spec:

For the predefined operators, the number of bits to shift is computed as follows:

When the type of x is int or uint, the shift count is given by the low-order five bits of count. In other words, the shift count is computed from count & 0x1F.
When the type of x is long or ulong, the shift count is given by the low-order six bits of count. In other words, the shift count is computed from count & 0x3F.

If the resulting shift count is zero, the shift operators simply return the value of x.

The bottom 6 bits of 64 are all zero, so the result is just x.

Besides, 1ul<<64 would move the 1st bit to the 65th place.

@PanagiotisKanavos: I'm not sure that's really a "besides" so much as "the reason only the bottom 6 bits are used".

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators#shift-count-of-the-shift-operators

If the type of x is long or ulong, the shift count is defined by the low-order six bits of the right-hand operand. That is, the shift count is computed from count & 0x3F (or count & 0b_11_1111).

